# Snippet issue in SXA 1.7.1

Tags: sxa

we are using Sitecore 9 Update-2 and SXA 1.7.1

I created one snippet item named TestSnippet under /Data/Snippets and added one promo component inside TestSnippet using experience editor. now I created one partial design named EmptyContainer1 and added one container component inside EmptyContainer1 in main placeholder using experience editor.

I associated EmptyContainer1 along with other partial designs to page design named TestPageDesign.

now created one page inside home node named TestPage and associated with TestPageDesign and opened in experience editor.

I can see that placeholder area where I added container but unable to drag and drop Snippet component in Composites section in tool box.

could anyone please help me on this.

my requirement is:

1. in **TestPage**, I'll add snippet component with TestSnippet where I
   have promo component and will change the datasource for promo component.
2. in **TestPage2**, I'll add snippet component with TestSnippet where I have promo component and will change the datasource for promo component.

so idea is that I want to use this promo in multiple pages with diferent datasource so content can be different as per page requirement which could not be achieved using partial design so was exploring snippet.

Comment: If you mean "unable to drag & drop", does the container turn pink or blue? Or is the snippet just not in the toolbox? Or do you get an error?  If there is no error, I would first check if you have no placeholder restrictions or such..

Comment: Snippet is there in tool box. it worked yesterday for me but all of a sudden it stopped working today. it looks like placeholder main/container-1 is restricted and not allowing me to add any component. I'm able to add snippet inside EmptyContainer1 partial design but not in page under home node.